# How to reset instrumented classes in Javaagent

Tags: java, javaagents

I'm using java instrumentation API to change the byte code of few classes. How can I deinstrument those classes at runtime?

Comment: Not sure it's possible. I suppose you could implementation a 2nd agent which applies the inverse modification, but could get tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You remove the class file transformer and call Instrumentation.retransformClasses on any class you want to reset.

This requires that you did not change the structure of classes in your original transform, but only the byte code of existing methods.